# First project! Arduino uno r3 says "no matching function for call to 'SevSeg::SevSeg()'"

Tags: arduino, seven-segment-display

I was following this tutorial, and everything is wired correctly as far as I can tell, but my 7seg display is only showing 8888.
I tried uploading the code to the controller but I get back "no matching function for call to 'SevSeg::SevSeg()'"
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

full error message:

```
DaysCounterTest:4:8: error: no matching function for call to 'SevSeg::SevSeg()'

 SevSeg sevseg; //Instantiate a seven segment controller object

        ^~~~~~

In file included from C:\Users\Cel\Documents\Arduino\DaysCounterTest\DaysCounterTest.ino:2:0:

C:\Users\Cel\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Firmware/SevSeg.h:49:3: note: candidate: SevSeg::SevSeg(byte*, byte*, byte, byte, bool, bool, bool)

   SevSeg( byte segmentPinsIn[], byte digitPinsIn[], byte numDigitsIn = 4, byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_ANODE,

   ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Cel\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Firmware/SevSeg.h:49:3: note:   candidate expects 7 arguments, 0 provided

C:\Users\Cel\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Firmware/SevSeg.h:46:7: note: candidate: constexpr SevSeg::SevSeg(const SevSeg&)

 class SevSeg

       ^~~~~~

C:\Users\Cel\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Firmware/SevSeg.h:46:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

C:\Users\Cel\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Firmware/SevSeg.h:46:7: note: candidate: constexpr SevSeg::SevSeg(SevSeg&&)

C:\Users\Cel\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Firmware/SevSeg.h:46:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

C:\Users\Cel\Documents\Arduino\DaysCounterTest\DaysCounterTest.ino: In function 'void setup()':

DaysCounterTest:87:50: error: no matching function for call to 'SevSeg::begin(byte&, byte&, byte [4], byte [8], bool&, bool&, bool&, bool&)'

   updateWithDelays, leadingZeros, disableDecPoint);

                                                  ^

In file included from C:\Users\Cel\Documents\Arduino\DaysCounterTest\DaysCounterTest.ino:2:0:

C:\Users\Cel\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Firmware/SevSeg.h:53:8: note: candidate: void SevSeg::begin(byte*, byte*, byte, byte, bool, bool, bool)

   void begin( byte segmentPinsIn[], byte digitPinsIn[], byte numDigitsIn = 4, byte hardwareConfig = COMMON_ANODE,

        ^~~~~

C:\Users\Cel\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Firmware/SevSeg.h:53:8: note:   candidate expects 7 arguments, 8 provided

exit status 1

no matching function for call to 'SevSeg::SevSeg()'



This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: Please post the code you uploaded and provide a link to the tutorial you mentioned.

Comment: The problem arises long before uploading, when compiling your tutorial code. So it's not a wiring question (yet). If that does not help yet: Restart the tutorial from scratch and follow instructions precisely.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed my links were not posted in my original post.
I found that the libraries I needed were not importing correctly, more specifically the sevseg one. I needed to import another one with it. Now the 7 seg display is showing up correctly

Comment: This answer does nothing but report your project status.  It doesn't belong here, as it doesn't show what you did wrong and how you fixed it.